# How to get data back from stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to debug\execute a SP from t-sql (sql server 2008) and when I execute the following sql it returns only a message 'Command(s) completed successfully'.

I know the SP is returning the data in a table via the @RETURN_VALUE parameter, how do I get this to display in sql query window.

```
exec STARMS.dbo.GetMetaData @@Assembly=13366,@@Namespace=NULL,@@ParameterName=NULL,@@Standard=0,@@Timestamp=NULL
```

The SP looks something like this ( removed the main body) the interesting part is the creation of the temp table and then returning the contents of the temp table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMetaData]
    @@Assembly Sql_Variant = NULL,
    @@Namespace Varchar(30) = NULL,
    @@ParameterName Varchar(40) = NULL,
    @@Standard Bit = 0,
    @@Timestamp DateTime = NULL
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (AssemblyId Int, Namespace Varchar(30), ParameterName Varchar(40), Value Varchar(100))

    -- Does loads of stuff and then inserts into @ResultTable table...

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    -- Return the result
    SELECT AssemblyId, Namespace, ParameterName, [Value]
        FROM @ResultTable

    RETURN
```

Note: the reason I'm asking the question is because I'm trying to look at the performance of the SP in SQL Server 2008 and I'm unsure why this doesn't return the data in the query window.

Comment: Why are you naming your parameters with two `@@` signs? This typically indicates built-in functions (e.g. `@@IDENTITY`). Your variables and parameters should be defined with a single `@` sign, IMHO. Also, why bother with `SET NOCOUNT OFF`? Does your app rely on the completed in proc messages (e.g. `n row(s) affected`)?

Comment: this is not my code I am just looking at from the app that is using it and trying to trace issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your full code of SP, may be somewhere there is a RETURN statement, so - the SP will not return any data (pay attention on `IF SomeContition IS TRUE RETURN`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMetaData]
    @@Assembly Sql_Variant = NULL,
    @@Namespace Varchar(30) = NULL,
    @@ParameterName Varchar(40) = NULL,
    @@Standard Bit = 0,
    @@Timestamp DateTime = NULL
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (AssemblyId Int, Namespace Varchar(30), ParameterName Varchar(40), Value Varchar(100))

    -- Does loads of stuff and then inserts into @ResultTable table...

    IF SomeContition IS TRUE RETURN

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    -- Return the result
    SELECT AssemblyId, Namespace, ParameterName, [Value]
        FROM @ResultTable

    RETURN
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not interested in the return code from the SP, I'm interested in the data...